# Extend an XML schema (AIXM) to allow arbitrary elements

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I'm struggling with `any` elements in a XML schema, here's the (abridged) type definition – a part of AIXM:

```xml
<xsd:element name="Ase" type="AirspaceType"/>

<xsd:complexType name="AirspaceType">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Airspace</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="txtName" type="txtName" minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Name (as published in AIP)</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute ref="source"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The following is therefore schema valid:

```xml
<Ase source="foobar">
  <txtName>Some Airspace</txtName>
</Ase>
```

I'd like to extend this schema to allow for any number of arbitrary elements following the last element of the sequence provided these elements begin with an underscore, for instance:

```xml
<Ase source="foobar">
  <txtName>Some Airspace</txtName>
  <_test>This should be valid</_test>
</Ase>
```

And:

```xml
<Ase source="foobar">
  <txtName>Some Airspace</txtName>
  <test>This should NOT valid since the element name doesn't begin with an underscore</test>
</Ase>
```

I've tried a couple of things, even asked AI for help, but the best I could come up with is:

```xml
<xsd:element name="Ase" type="AirspaceType"/>

<xsd:complexType name="AirspaceType">
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Airspace</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:element name="txtName" type="txtName" minOccurs="0">
      <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Name (as published in AIP)</xsd:documentation>
      </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xsd:annotation>
      <xsd:documentation>Unofficial extension</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyName">
      <xsd:pattern value="_.*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:any>
  <xsd:attribute ref="source"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

However, such a schema is invalid:

> element any: Schemas validity error : Element '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}any': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attribute, {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}attributeGroup, {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyAttribute ).

Is it even possible to extend the schema in this way and if so, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the current version 1.1 of the schema language (supported by Xerces Java, Saxon EE, https://pypi.org/project/xmlschema/, and I think also Altova) you can write an assertion in the form of e.g.

```
<xs:complexType name="AirspaceType">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Airspace</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="txtName" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Name (as published in AIP)</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:documentation>Unofficial extension</xs:documentation>
            </xs:annotation>
        </xs:any>
    </xs:sequence>

    <xs:attribute name="source" type="xs:string"/>
    
    <xs:assert id="name_prefix" test="every $child in *[not(self::txtName)] satisfies starts-with(local-name($child), '_')"></xs:assert>
</xs:complexType>
```

That would make your sample with `_test` valid and the one with `test` invalid.

Whether that is a good idea in the world of XML and schemas to use assertions that way is another question; I would think that most people want the grammar to clearly define the types and names of elements and not to put some syntax rules for names into assertions; but if that is your requirement then I think an assertion is likely the (only) way the schema language allows you to express that.

Of course the other error in your posted sample is simply the placement of `xs:any` outside of the `xs:sequence`.

Comment: The underscore elements are for inhouse development only. Thanks for the hint on `assert`, I'll check whether we can adapt our toolchain to support XSD 1.1 somehow.